# What is the Ayatana Project?

Tags: design

What does it do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The Ayatana Project is the collective
>   project that houses user interface,
>   design and interaction projects
>   started by Canonical.

For example they have designed:

```
   * Application Indicators
   * The Me Menu
   * Messaging Menu
   * Notify OSD
   * Unity
```

More information: https://launchpad.net/ayatana

Comment: even more info: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ayatana/