# Can I configure Unity search result behavior?

Tags: 11.04, unity

I wanted to ask if it were possible to configure the unity search results in this way:

- installed programs are always shown expanded.
- programs "ready for installation" are removed and not included in the search.

I am sure ŕemoving the search and display for not installed programs will speed up the search and save valuable screenspace (I'm on a Dell Mini here).

Why installed programs aren't shown in the first place is a mystery to me.

Comment: I suggest that you bring this up on the Ayatana [mailing list](https://launchpad.net/~ayatana) - for more on what Ayatana does look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1004/what-is-the-ayatana-project)

Answer (score 1):

Both of these are currently unconfigurable in Unity in 11.10 and 11.04, sorry.