# What is X-Ayatana?

Tags: ayatana

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Ayatana Project?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004/what-is-the-ayatana-project)

I've heard of the X-Ayatana mailing list or something like that..

Also when we create .desktop files adding quicklists needs the one line to be added at the start having **X-Ayatana** mentioned...

What is this exactly?

A detailed answer would be gr8..

From community members would be best :)

Answer (score 0):

For the .desktop files, non-standard keys are required to start with X-, as per the FreeDesktop Desktop File Spec.